# Java Applets refuse to work in Safari or Firefox

Tags: java, web-browser

- Mac OS X 10.7.5
- Safari 6.0.2
- Firefox 18.0.1
- Java 1.6.0_37 64 bit
- Firefox Java Applet Plugin v 1.6.0.37

Safari Preferences has the "Enable Java" box checked. Firefox has the Java Applet Plug-in installed and enabled. I don't understand why Java Applets refuse to work in either browser.

What do I need to do get to them running?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Nope, it does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/10/16/software-update-removes-apple-provided-java-applet-plug-in) on Apple Insider. You probably don't have a Applet plugin installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

And if you did re-install it, it probably got blocked again the next day due to the malware issue: http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/155735/apple-again-blocks-latest-version-of-java-through-os-x-anti-malware-system

Looks there is a fix for Snow Leopard (see Software Update) but not for Lion varieties...